# Excluding some results from a table-Web Scraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm scraping a table from a website using Python. My code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

print('Scraping NJ Dept of Banking...')
print()

NJurl = 'https://www.state.nj.us/dobi/bnk_depositories/appwebinfo.htm'
NJr = requests.get(NJurl, headers = headers)

NJsoup = BeautifulSoup(NJr.text, 'html.parser')

NJlist = []
for tr in NJsoup.find_all('td')[12:30]:
    NJresult = (tr.text.strip())
    NJlist.append(' '.join(NJresult.split()))
    print(' '.join(NJresult.split()))

if not NJlist:
    NJresult = 'No Transactions'
    print(NJresult)
    NJlist.append(NJresult)
    print()
```

The code above works well, the results look like this:

```
The Bank of Princeton
Branch
Application to establish a branch office on or about December 31, 2019 at 1839 Chestnut Street Philadelphia, PA (Philadelphia County County) 7/15/2019 Accepted
7/15/2019
Accepted

Two River Community Bank
Branch
Expedited application to establish a branch office at 442 Highway 35 Middletown, NJ (Monmouth County) 7/15/2019 Opened
7/15/2019
Opened

Two River Community Bank
Main Office Relocation
Application to relocate its main office from 1250 Route 35, Middletown, Middlesex County, 07748 to 766 Shrewsbury Avenue Tinton Falls, NJ (Monmouth County) 7/15/2019 Opened
7/15/2019
Opened
```

The problem is I would like to exclude certain types of events. For example, I don't need to see the first two events involving branches. I've adjusted a portion of my code to try to account for this:

```
for tr in NJsoup.find_all('td')[12:30]:
    NJresult = (tr.text.strip())
    if 'branch' not in NJresult.lower():
        NJlist.append(' '.join(NJresult.split()))
        print(' '.join(NJresult.split()))
```

The problem with that  adjustment is that it just eliminates specific sentences with the word 'branch' in them, not the entire event. For example the output with the adjusted code looks like this:

```
The Bank of Princeton
7/15/2019
Accepted

Two River Community Bank
7/15/2019
Opened

Two River Community Bank
Main Office Relocation
Application to relocate its main office from 1250 Route 35, Middletown, Middlesex County, 07748 to 766 Shrewsbury Avenue Tinton Falls, NJ (Monmouth County) 7/15/2019 Opened
7/15/2019
Opened
```

Is there a way I can go about skipping any output for a branch transaction so the output looks like this?

```
Two River Community Bank
Main Office Relocation
Application to relocate its main office from 1250 Route 35, Middletown, Middlesex County, 07748 to 766 Shrewsbury Avenue Tinton Falls, NJ (Monmouth County) 7/15/2019 Opened
7/15/2019
Opened
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you named your iterator `tr`, you are not iterating through rows, but actually through `<td>`s. I would iterate through relevant rows and then decide in each row if I want to include it or not. Something like this:

find the rows 
`rows = NJsoup.find_all('tr')[6:-2:2]`

then iterate through them:

```
for row in rows:
    new_record = []
    for td in row.find_all('td'):
        if td.text.strip() == 'Branch':
            break
        new_record(td.text.strip())
    else:
        NJlist.append('\n'.join(new_record)
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Would you mind explaining the slicing in the 'rows' statement? I've never seen it like that before.

Comment: the slicing notation is `[from:to:step]`. `from` is obvious, `to` is also obvious, negative number is used because there was another table with couple of rows, so I want to omit those and last `step` is there because I noticed that there is an empty `<tr>` element between the rows of the table, so I wanted to skip every other row to include only the rows with information.